# slide div left and right depending on the content of the div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

First off, I do apologize if this is a bit vague. I will try my best to explain this as best as I can.

I am trying to create a slideshow affect with a div content.

the content of the div is not images but they are HTML stuff.... buttons to be exact.

I have a div with an `overflow hidden` and an **inner div** inside this div with a width of 500000px. I know this is a ridiculous width size but i only done this because the content of this div is pulled from a database and i don't know how much data might be in there in the future. i did try `width:auto;` but that didn't work.

anyway, this is what I have in my page:

```
<div style="padding-left:15px; overflow:hidden;">
<div class="innerBottom" style="width:500000px;">
<?PHP echo $date_list; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

now, I need to create a function using jquery that would allow me to slide the `innerBottom` to left or right using two buttons.

for example if the content is pulled from the database and there is not enough content for the slide to work then the slide is disabled but if there is enough content then the slide to the right is enabled at first and when the slided to the right once, then the slide to left is enabled.

I hope this makes sense and someone could help me out with this.

I did try something like this using jquery:

```
    <script>


    $("#button-bottom").click(function () {
  $('.innerBottom').animate({'margin-left':'3px'});
}, function() {
 $('.innerBottom').animate({'margin-left':'1003px'});
});

</script>
```

but that only does the left slide once and the inner div disappears for good.

Thanks in advance

Comment: jQuery sliders have been covered to death, as seen in the right hand panel 'Related'. This is one of the few scenarios where I would advocate using a plugin as they're in abundance, streamlined and will deal with a lot of edge cases for you.

Comment: I disagree, making those slideshows is good for practise. I've done plenty.. in the beggining that was a fuss, but in the end I think it has saved me some hassle - knowing my own code and exactly what it does makes it easy to adjust for changes.

Comment: @speak, I rather not to use a plugin that is bloated (most plugins are) and as stated above this can be done by writing own code. also, most of the plugins do not work with html content.

Comment: @user3806613 if you want to write it yourself, please post a http://jsfiddle.net showcasing your problem and I'll help amend it to point you in the right direction.

I too dislike plugins as they're usually bloated - but really, slideshows probably account for most % of jQuery plugins, they're very heavily documented and streamlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one super simple example I wrote quickly.. see if you can transform it for your needs. Good luck!

http://jsfiddle.net/e4g9h/1/

HTML

```
<div id="mainWrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="slider" style="">
            <div class="contentDiv">
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="Button 1"/>
            </div>
            <div class="contentDiv">
                <input type="button" class="buttons" value="Button 2"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="left" class="triggerSlide">Go Left</div>
    <div id="right" class="triggerSlide">Go Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#mainWrapper{
   width: 800px;
   }

#wrapper{
   width: 800px;
   height: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 1px solid black;
   }

#slider{
   width: 1600px;
   text-align: center;
   }

.contentDiv{
   width: 800px; 
   float: left;
   }

.buttons{
   width: 600px;
   height: 90px;
   }

.triggerSlide{
   text-align: center;
   padding: 5px;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   cursor: pointer;
   }
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var margin = 0;
$('.triggerSlide').on('click',function(){
    var amountDivs = $('.contentDiv').length;
    var whereTo = $(this).attr('id');

    whereTo == 'left' ? margin -= 800 : margin += 800;

    if(parseInt(margin) > 0){
        margin = 0;
        return false;
        }
    else if(margin <= -Math.abs(amountDivs * 800)){
        margin = -Math.abs((parseInt(amountDivs) -1) * 800);
        return false;
        }

    $('#slider').animate({
        marginLeft: margin
        });
    });
});
```